# Ajax POST call error "application/json is not a valid input type"

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, google-api, google-sheets-api

I am trying to execute an ajax call but keeps getting error 415 - unsupported media type. I even tried setting header `Content-Type : application/json` but it still doesn't work.

#### Code:

```
function addTaskInSheet(taskToUpdate){

  var accessToken = $rootScope.accessToken;
  var groupId = $rootScope.groupId;
  var url = "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/" + groupId + "/od6/private/full" ;
  var updatedTask = {};
   $.ajax({
      url:url,
       type: 'POST',
       async: false,
       data: JSON.stringify(taskToUpdate),

       dataType: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        crossDomain: true,
        beforeSend: function (xhr) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + accessToken);
            xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type','application/json');
        },
       success: function (response) {
            updatedTask = response;
            console.log(updatedTask);

        }, error: function (response) {

          console.log(response);
       }
   });
   return updatedTask;
}
```

#### Error in console:

[image]

Comment: Are you sure the [API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/worksheets) supports JSON? It doesn't mention support anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `Accept` header in your ajax `beforeSend` method, as:

```
..
beforeSend: function (xhr) {
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + accessToken);    
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Accept','application/json');
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type','application/json');
},
..
```

Comment: I tried adding Accept header. But it still shows the same error.